# How to prevent Mac from stopping long-running processes when I leave laptop on overnight

Tags: macos, process, logout

I have a batch upload script that is making a bunch of API calls to the web that I want running continuously overnight without interruption so it can make more progress while I'm asleep.

Unfortunately every time I wake up and come back to it the processes are seemingly paused and an alert says something like "Terminal prevented successful logout". The browser windows have all closed and yet the terminal stayed open, and when I resume using the laptop the processes start right back where they left off. But I can tell they were **not** running that whole time in the night.

I am not sure why this is happening or how to prevent it. I've tried increasing the time to 3 hours where my computer doesn't dim/sleep. But I'm not sure what to do to keep it running all night. (I don't need the screen to be on, just the processes to continue running without interruption / logout).

Wondering what to do.

Comment: Need to know what Mac specifically, & OS version might be useful. Desktops behave differently to laptops for sleep scenarios.

Comment: I am on a Macbook Pro, High Sierra, 10.13.6.

Comment: See this for pics of the relevant section - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361125/2018-mac-book-pro-doesnt-go-to-sleep-sleep-after-being-idle I don't have a laptop, but I think if you set as per the top pic then don't close the lid, that should help.

Comment: Sorry... bottom pic, my bad